# Why this doesn't work on array numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm playing with array just learning javascript basics, I got a basic function here whenever I change the passing arguments to a number the `console.log(arr[i][j][k])` gives me undefined, but if it's a string it logs the number.

```
function array(arr) {
    for(var i=0;i < arr.length;i++){
      for(var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            for(var k=0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++){
              console.log(arr[i][j][k])
            }
      }
    }
}

array(['1','2',['3','4'],['5','6','7']]); // change to a number and will give undefined.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are calling `.length` within the loop. Numbers don't have a `.length` method so it returns undefined. Strings however, do have that method.

As an example of what would work, you could check if the index within the array is a number, then `console.log` that and `continue` (next index in the array).

```js
function array(arr) {
  for(var i=0;i < arr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){    
      if (typeof arr[i][j] === 'number') {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
        continue;
      }
      
      for(var k=0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++){
        console.log(arr[i][j][k])
      }
    }
  }
}

array(['1','2',['3','4'],['5','6', 7]]);
```

You would need to perform this check within each loop to account for numbers any where in the array.

Building off @chazsolo's answer, here is a non ES6 way of doing the same thing, just in case throwing ES6 syntax in to the mix is confusing

```js
var allItems = function (array) {
  var i = 0;
  // Loop through all items
  for (i; i < array.length; ++i) {
    // If this item is an array
    // You could also use typeof or Array.isArray as below
    if (toString.call(array[i]) === '[object Array]') {
      allItems(array[i]); // run this function again with this array
      continue; // move to next item
    }
    
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
}

allItems([1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]);

allItems(['1', '2', ['3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7']]);

allItems(['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', ['e', ['f', ['g']]]]]]]);
```

First, we loop through all the items in the array. We check if the item itself is an array (I call `toString` here which returns `[object Array]` if it is an array). If it is an array, then we run the same function for this array (recursion) and then skip to the next item since we don't need to do anything else with this one.

If it isn't an array, then we can just console log it (here we assume it is a number or string, watch out for objects thrown in to the mix).

Answer (score 3):

Building off of @CarlMarkham's answer, which explains why you should not call `.length` on each item of the array (you aren't type checking, so `.length` is undefined for Numbers).

It's dissatisfying that you are restricting yourself to 3 levels of nested arrays. This is a great example for how recursion can help make this much more flexible. Consider the following using ES6:

```js
const allItems = (array) => {
  for (let i of array) {
    Array.isArray(i) ? allItems(i) : console.log(i);
  }
}

allItems([1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]);

allItems(['1', '2', ['3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7']]);

allItems(['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', ['e', ['f', ['g']]]]]]]);
```

Comment: where can i find the methods you use here?

Comment: There's many resources online, but you could start by reviewing MDN's documentation on [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion), [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), and [ES6 support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the above two solutions use recursive functions, meaning that the function calls itself, over and over, until the "base case" is met. In these cases, they call the function allItems() within itself.

This points out the advantages of using recursive functions for complex data structures. That is, that recursive functions execute a function or operation as many times as you need, regardless of how complex your data structure is, regardless of how nested it is, whether you know how many dimensions there are or not.

So, if you know your data structure is double nested, a loop is a great solution because you know how many loops are needed to access all the elements within those dimensions.

However, if you have a very multi-dimensional data structure that has a number of nested structures and elements that you may not be aware of, you won't know how many loops to use, and a recursive function will take care of this complexity based on your conditional "base cases". As someone said before, recursion will check a condition before executing each loop, unlike standard loops.

Hope that helps you when dealing with complex data structures in the future.